# my jquery slider stopped working

Tags: jquery, slider

/**
 * jquery.slitslider.js v1.1.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2012, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */

;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

```
'use strict';

/*
* debouncedresize: special jQuery event that happens once after a window resize
*
* latest version and complete README available on Github:
* https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/blob/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js
*
* Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
* Licensed under the MIT license.
*/
var $event = $.event,
$special,
resizeTimeout;

$special = $event.special.debouncedresize = {
    setup: function() {
        $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $( this ).off( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
            args = arguments,
            dispatch = function() {
                // set correct event type
                event.type = "debouncedresize";
                $event.dispatch.apply( context, args );
            };

        if ( resizeTimeout ) {
            clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
        }

        execAsap ?
            dispatch() :
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout( dispatch, $special.threshold );
    },
    threshold: 20
};

// global
var $window = $( window ),
    $document = $( document ),
    Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

$.Slitslider = function( options, element ) {

    this.$elWrapper = $( element );
    this._init( options );

};

$.Slitslider.defaults = {
    // transitions speed
    speed : 800,
    // if true the item's slices will also animate the opacity value
    optOpacity : false,
    // amount (%) to translate both slices - adjust as necessary
    translateFactor : 230,
    // maximum possible angle
    maxAngle : 25,
    // maximum possible scale
    maxScale : 2,
    // slideshow on / off
    autoplay : false,
    // keyboard navigation
    keyboard : true,
    // time between transitions
    interval : 4000,
    // callbacks
    onBeforeChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; },
    onAfterChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; }
};

$.Slitslider.prototype = {

    _init : function( options ) {

        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slitslider.defaults, options );

        // https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2870
        this.transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
            'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition' : 'transitionend'
        };
        this.transEndEventName = this.transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ];
        // suport for css 3d transforms and css transitions
        this.support = Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
        // the slider
        this.$el = this.$elWrapper.children( '.sl-slider' );
        // the slides
        this.$slides = this.$el.children( '.sl-slide' ).hide();
        // total slides
        this.slidesCount = this.$slides.length;
        // current slide
        this.current = 0;
        // control if it's animating
        this.isAnimating = false;
        // get container size
        this._getSize();
        // layout
        this._layout();
        // load some events
        this._loadEvents();
        // slideshow
        if( this.options.autoplay ) {

            this._startSlideshow();

        }

    },
    // gets the current container width & height
    _getSize : function() {

        this.size = {
            width : this.$elWrapper.outerWidth( true ),
            height : this.$elWrapper.outerHeight( true )
        };

    },
    _layout : function() {

        this.$slideWrapper = $( '<div class="sl-slides-wrapper" />' );

        // wrap the slides
        this.$slides.wrapAll( this.$slideWrapper ).each( function( i ) {

            var $slide = $( this ),
                // vertical || horizontal
                orientation = $slide.data( 'orientation' );

            $slide.addClass( 'sl-slide-' + orientation )
                  .children()
                  .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content-wrapper" />' )
                  .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content" />' );

        } );

        // set the right size of the slider/slides for the current window size
        this._setSize();
        // show first slide
        this.$slides.eq( this.current ).show();

    },
    _navigate : function( dir, pos ) {

        if( this.isAnimating || this.slidesCount < 2 ) {

            return false;

        }

        this.isAnimating = true;

        var self = this,
            $currentSlide = this.$slides.eq( this.current );

        // if position is passed
        if( pos !== undefined ) {

            this.current = pos;

        }
        // if not check the boundaries
        else if( dir === 'next' ) {

            this.current = this.current < this.slidesCount - 1 ? ++this.current : 0;

        }
        else if( dir === 'prev' ) {

            this.current = this.current > 0 ? --this.current : this.slidesCount - 1;

        }

        this.options.onBeforeChange( $currentSlide, this.current );

        // next slide to be shown
        var $nextSlide = this.$slides.eq( this.current ),
            // the slide we want to cut and animate
            $movingSlide = ( dir === 'next' ) ? $currentSlide : $nextSlide,

            // the following are the data attrs set for each slide
            configData = $movingSlide.data(),
            config = {};

        config.orientation = configData.orientation || 'horizontal',
        config.slice1angle = configData.slice1Rotation || 0,
        config.slice1scale = configData.slice1Scale || 1,
        config.slice2angle = configData.slice2Rotation || 0,
        config.slice2scale = configData.slice2Scale || 1;

        this._validateValues( config );

        var cssStyle = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                marginTop : -this.size.height / 2
            } : {
                marginLeft : -this.size.width / 2
            },
            // default slide's slices style
            resetStyle = {
                'transform' : 'translate(0%,0%) rotate(0deg) scale(1)',
                opacity : 1 
            },
            // slice1 style
            slice1Style = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                'transform' : 'translateY(-' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice1angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice1scale + ')'
            } : {
                'transform' : 'translateX(-' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice1angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice1scale + ')'
            },
            // slice2 style
            slice2Style = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                'transform' : 'translateY(' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice2angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice2scale + ')'
            } : {
                'transform' : 'translateX(' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice2angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice2scale + ')'
            };

        if( this.options.optOpacity ) {

            slice1Style.opacity = 0;
            slice2Style.opacity = 0;

        }

        // we are adding the classes sl-trans-elems and sl-trans-back-elems to the slide that is either coming "next"
        // or going "prev" according to the direction.
        // the idea is to make it more interesting by giving some animations to the respective slide's elements
        //( dir === 'next' ) ? $nextSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-elems' ) : $currentSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-back-elems' );

        $currentSlide.removeClass( 'sl-trans-elems' );

        var transitionProp = {
            'transition' : 'all ' + this.options.speed + 'ms ease-in-out'
        };

        // add the 2 slices and animate them
        $movingSlide.css( 'z-index', this.slidesCount )
                    .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                    .wrap( $( '<div class="sl-content-slice" />' ).css( transitionProp ) )
                    .parent()
                    .cond(
                        dir === 'prev', 
                        function() {

                            var slice = this;
                            this.css( slice1Style );
                            setTimeout( function() {

                                slice.css( resetStyle );

                            }, 50 );

                        }, 
                        function() {

                            var slice = this;
                            setTimeout( function() {

                                slice.css( slice1Style );

                            }, 50 );

                        }
                    )
                    .clone()
                    .appendTo( $movingSlide )
                    .cond(
                        dir === 'prev', 
                        function() {

                            var slice = this;
                            this.css( slice2Style );
                            setTimeout( function() {

                                $currentSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-back-elems' );

                                if( self.support ) {

                                    slice.css( resetStyle ).on( self.transEndEventName, function() {

                                        self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                    } );

                                }
                                else {

                                    self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                }

                            }, 50 );

                        },
                        function() {

                            var slice = this;
                            setTimeout( function() {

                                $nextSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-elems' );

                                if( self.support ) {

                                    slice.css( slice2Style ).on( self.transEndEventName, function() {

                                        self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                    } );

                                }
                                else {

                                    self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                }

                            }, 50 );

                        }
                    )
                    .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                    .css( cssStyle );

        $nextSlide.show();

    },
    _validateValues : function( config ) {

        // OK, so we are restricting the angles and scale values here.
        // This is to avoid the slices wrong sides to be shown.
        // you can adjust these values as you wish but make sure you also ajust the
        // paddings of the slides and also the options.translateFactor value and scale data attrs
        if( config.slice1angle > this.options.maxAngle || config.slice1angle < -this.options.maxAngle ) {

            config.slice1angle = this.options.maxAngle;

        }
        if( config.slice2angle > this.options.maxAngle  || config.slice2angle < -this.options.maxAngle ) {

            config.slice2angle = this.options.maxAngle;

        }
        if( config.slice1scale > this.options.maxScale || config.slice1scale <= 0 ) {

            config.slice1scale = this.options.maxScale;

        }
        if( config.slice2scale > this.options.maxScale || config.slice2scale <= 0 ) {

            config.slice2scale = this.options.maxScale;

        }
        if( config.orientation !== 'vertical' && config.orientation !== 'horizontal' ) {

            config.orientation = 'horizontal'

        }

    },
    _onEndNavigate : function( $slice, $oldSlide, dir ) {

        // reset previous slide's style after next slide is shown
        var $slide = $slice.parent(),
            removeClasses = 'sl-trans-elems sl-trans-back-elems';

        // remove second slide's slice
        $slice.remove();
        // unwrap..
        $slide.css( 'z-index', 1 )
              .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
              .unwrap();

        // hide previous current slide
        $oldSlide.hide().removeClass( removeClasses );
        $slide.removeClass( removeClasses );
        // now we can navigate again..
        this.isAnimating = false;
        this.options.onAfterChange( $slide, this.current );

    },
    _setSize : function() {

        // the slider and content wrappers will have the window's width and height
        var cssStyle = {
            width : this.size.width,
            height : this.size.height
        };

        this.$el.css( cssStyle ).find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' ).css( cssStyle );

    },
    _loadEvents : function() {

        var self = this;

        $window.on( 'debouncedresize.slitslider', function( event ) {

            // update size values
            self._getSize();
            // set the sizes again
            self._setSize();

        } );

        if ( this.options.keyboard ) {

            $document.on( 'keydown.slitslider', function(e) {

                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
                    arrow = {
                        left: 37,
                        up: 38,
                        right: 39,
                        down: 40
                    };

                switch (keyCode) {

                    case arrow.left :

                        self._stopSlideshow();
                        self._navigate( 'prev' );
                        break;

                    case arrow.right :

                        self._stopSlideshow();
                        self._navigate( 'next' );
                        break;

                }

            } );

        }

    },
    _startSlideshow: function() {

        var self = this;

        this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {

            self._navigate( 'next' );

            if ( self.options.autoplay ) {

                self._startSlideshow();

            }

        }, this.options.interval );

    },
    _stopSlideshow: function() {

        if ( this.options.autoplay ) {

            clearTimeout( this.slideshow );
            this.isPlaying = false;
            this.options.autoplay = false;

        }

    },
    _destroy : function( callback ) {

        this.$el.off( '.slitslider' ).removeData( 'slitslider' );
        $window.off( '.slitslider' );
        $document.off( '.slitslider' );
        this.$slides.each( function( i ) {

            var $slide = $( this ),
                $content = $slide.find( 'div.sl-content' ).children();

            $content.appendTo( $slide );
            $slide.children( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' ).remove();

        } );
        this.$slides.unwrap( this.$slideWrapper ).hide();
        this.$slides.eq( 0 ).show();
        if( callback ) {

            callback.call();

        }

    },
    // public methos: adds more slides to the slider
    add : function( $slides, callback ) {

        this.$slides = this.$slides.add( $slides );

        var self = this;


        $slides.each( function( i ) {

            var $slide = $( this ),
                // vertical || horizontal
                orientation = $slide.data( 'orientation' );

            $slide.hide().addClass( 'sl-slide-' + orientation )
                  .children()
                  .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content-wrapper" />' )
                  .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content" />' )
                  .end()
                  .appendTo( self.$el.find( 'div.sl-slides-wrapper' ) );

        } );

        this._setSize();

        this.slidesCount = this.$slides.length;

        if ( callback ) {

            callback.call( $items );

        }

    },
    // public method: shows next slide
    next : function() {

        this._stopSlideshow();
        this._navigate( 'next' );

    },
    // public method: shows previous slide
    previous : function() {

        this._stopSlideshow();
        this._navigate( 'prev' );

    },
    // public method: goes to a specific slide
    jump : function( pos ) {

        pos -= 1;

        if( pos === this.current || pos >= this.slidesCount || pos < 0 ) {

            return false;

        }

        this._stopSlideshow();
        this._navigate( pos > this.current ? 'next' : 'prev', pos );

    },
    // public method: starts the slideshow
    // any call to next(), previous() or jump() will stop the slideshow
    play : function() {

        if( !this.isPlaying ) {

            this.isPlaying = true;

            this._navigate( 'next' );
            this.options.autoplay = true;
            this._startSlideshow();

        }

    },
    // public method: pauses the slideshow
    pause : function() {

        if( this.isPlaying ) {

            this._stopSlideshow();

        }

    },
    // public method: check if isAnimating is true
    isActive : function() {

        return this.isAnimating;

    },
    // publicc methos: destroys the slicebox instance
    destroy : function( callback ) {

        this._destroy( callback );

    }

};

var logError = function( message ) {

    if ( window.console ) {

        window.console.error( message );

    }

};

$.fn.slitslider = function( options ) {

    var self = $.data( this, 'slitslider' );

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            if ( !self ) {

                logError( "cannot call methods on slitslider prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;

            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( self[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {

                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for slitslider self" );
                return;

            }

            self[ options ].apply( self, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            if ( self ) {

                self._init();

            }
            else {

                self = $.data( this, 'slitslider', new $.Slitslider( options, this ) );

            }

        });

    }

    return self;

};
```

} )( jQuery, window );

Comment: Can't expect any help by dropping a mountain of code into a post with no explanation whatsoever of history

Comment: charlietfl - No need to be rude...

Comment: For those that can help, I appreciate it and please let me know if there's any other information you need to help me fix this. The history is that it was working at one point and now it isn't working. This is the site http://euphorichealing.com/index.php

Comment: How can that be perceived as rude? Simple statement of fact. Code doesn't often just stop working without something having changed

Comment: your slider works fine for me when I click the buttons, are you saying it is supposed to begin switching automatically and it isnt? charlietfi's right "stopped working" is pretty vauge

Comment: @charlietfl - Regardless of too much or too little information, if your aim was to help you would have just asked for more information instead of making a snarky comment in regards to what you say is a simple statement of fact. Your further responses are not needed unless you can be helpful thanks.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yes it does work when you click. Yes it is supposed to be an automatic slider as well.

Answer (score 0):

On line 572 of `index.php` try changing `autoplay : false` to `autoplay : true`

Comment: Glad it helped, @charlietfl is right though, next time take a moment to explain what the expected behaviour is and what it's doing instead. More people will be able to help if we can understand what the issue is :)